# Perfomance issue while using stanford lexicalized parser in java

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am a newbie to Stanford NLP.I am using lexicalized parser for parsing the contents of the file and extracting the noun phrases.While parsing the line it is taking more time for generating a tree structure.

I am using a Tregex pattern to get noun phrases from a line.

I am using 1 MB file to parse,so it is taking, more than two hours for parsing as well as for extracting the noun phrases.

Here is my full code that i am using.

```
        Tree x = parser.apply(line);
        System.out.println("tree s=="+x);
        TregexPattern NPpattern = TregexPattern.compile("@NP <@/NN.?/");
        TregexMatcher matcher = NPpattern.matcher(x);

        while (matcher.findNextMatchingNode()) {
            Tree match = matcher.getMatch();
            List<TaggedWord> tWord = match.taggedYield();
            Iterator<TaggedWord> it = tWord.iterator();
            String str="";
            while(it.hasNext()){
                TaggedWord word = it.next();
                String taggedWord = word.tag();
                if(taggedWord.equals("NN")||taggedWord.equals("NNS")||taggedWord.equals("NNP")){
                    str = str+word.value()+" ";
                }
            }
       }
```

So please help me how to increase the performance or is there another way to optimize this code.

Thanks in advance
Gouse.

Comment: While not related to the issue, this would be a "good candidate" for the use of [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or an output stream. (Also, something should be done with the collected results :D)

Comment: Well parsing 1MB should take some time, but two hours? Have you profiled your code to know where all that time is spent?

Comment: How much memory have you allocated? It is possible for your memory usage to be just under that maximum specified, in which case the garbage collector will try very hard to free some space, which takes loads of time.

Comment: Hi Kutschkem,

        We have profiled our code and found that its taking more time in generating the tree structure at 

"Tree x = parser.apply(line);"

Thanks
Gouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full constituency parsing of text is just kind of slow.... If you stick with it, there may not be much that you can do.

But a couple of things to mention: (i) If you're not using the englishPCFG.ser.gz grammar, then you should, because it's faster than using englishFactored.seer.gz and (ii) Parsing very long sentences is especially slow, so if you can get by omitting or breaking very long sentences (say, over70 words), that can help a lot. In particular, if some of the text is from web scraping or whatever and has long lists of stuff that aren't really sentences, filtering or dividing them may help a lot.

The other direction you could go is that you appear to not really need a full parser but just an NP chunker (something that identifies minimal noun phrases in a text). These can be much faster as they don't build recursive structure. There isn't one at present among the Stanford NLP tools, but you can find some by searching for this term on the web.